# Unterschied Zielsetzung/Zielstellung

Tags: dialect

Mein früherer Chef (geboren in Sachsen) sagte einmal zu mir, dass man daran, ob jemand den Begriff *Zielstellung* oder *Zielsetzung* verwendet, erkennt, ob die Person aus Ost- oder Westdeutschland stammt. Ich weiß nicht, inwiefern diese Aussage ernst gemeint war, aber es würde mich sehr interessieren, ob dieser Unterschied tatsächlich existiert(e) und was der Hintergrund ist.

Meine bisherigen Recherchen haben dazu leider nichts ergeben, beide Wörter scheinen als synonym zu gelten.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Wo erfolgte die Recherche - als im Sinn von Seite x behandelt das Thema aber nicht dieses Wort/Seite y behandelt das Wort nur die Etymologie gibt nichts her? Ich habe das mal über den Gebrauch von Plasik vs. Plaste gehört.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Schon [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zielstellung) zeigt für *Zielstellung* unter Bedeutung die synonyme Verwendung von *Zielsetzung*  aber gleichzeitig auch **DDR**.

Die Wortverlaufskurve zeigt einen starken Rückgang in der Zeitspanne kurz vor und nach der Wiedervereinigung Deutschlands.

Auch die [Stasi Mediathek](https://www.stasi-mediathek.de/themen/schlagwort/Zielstellung/page/5/) zeigt eine Vielzahl von Dokumenten mit dem Begriff *Zielstellung*.

Mit einer Google-Suche nach "VEB Zielstellung" finden sich Original-Bildunterschriften zu alten Fotos (Bundesarchiv) aus damaligen Zeiten mit *Zielstellung*.

Dein ehemaliger Chef lag mit seinem "Gefühl" für die sprachliche Verwendung im damaligen "offiziellen" Sprachgebrach der DDR-Organe wohl richtig.

Comment: *Zielstellung* ist in den "alten Bundesländern" ungefähr so gebräuchlich wie *Kollektiv* und *Traktorist* - also gar nicht.

Comment: Danke, sehr interessant! Den Zusatz "DDR" hatte ich bei meiner eigenen Recherche gar nicht gesehen.